# Geometry proof question (AIMO)

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

This question is from an AIMO(Australian Intermediate Mathematics Olympiad) practise test, and I've been trying to work it out. The solution was not discussed for this question. I am looking for a complete proof.

QUESTION
In the triangle ABC let $M_a$, $M_b$ and $M_c$ be the midpoints of sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively; and $F_a$, $F_b$ and $F_c$ be the feet of the altitudes from $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively. Prove
that:

$M_aF_b + M_bF_c + M_cF_a = F_aM_b + F_bM_c + F_cM_a$

Comment: Do you mean the segments $M_aF_b, M_bF_c,\cdots$? I'm not sure what the product of points $M_a\cdot F_b$ would mean.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 They are segments, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint.

Because $$LHS=RHS=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.$$

For example $M_aF_b=\frac{a}{2}$ because $F_bMa$ is a median to the hypotenuse $BC$ of the right-angled triangle $BCF_b$.

Similarly, $F_aM_b=\frac{b}{2}.$

Comment: in $a$, $b$, and $c$, do you mean the side-lengths? of the triangle ABC?

Comment: Also, could you elaborate a bit more on how you got $\frac{a+b+c}{2}$?

Comment: @CitrusCornflakes   I added something. See now. In the standard notation $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides-lengths of $\Delta ABC.$

Comment: Thanks! Got everything now!